# Accessing 'this' inside an independent function in a Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a Dog Constructor as follows:

```
var Dog = function(name,type)
{
   this.name = name;
   this.type = type;
   this.normalObjFunc = function()
   {
      this.name = "kl";
   }
   var retfunc = function()
   { 
      return this.name;
   }
   return retfunc;
}
```

In the **retfunc** function() , I am trying to access this.name in the following way.

```
var dogObj = new Dog("hj","labrador");
alert(dogObj());
```

In the output , I get as "**result**" in the alert messageBox, I am not getting what does the o/p "**result**" ,means?

I have purposely not included *retfunc* to "this" object, does it mean I cant access *this.name* inside `retfunc()` because a SEparate "this" would be created?

I am also aware of the fact that assigning `var self =this` solves the problem.
I just want to know what is "**result**" which is the output and why not `undefined` ideally?

Comment: The way you are executing the returned function makes `this` refer to the global window object, so you ae actually getting `window.name` which is a window property containing the name of the window

Comment: Don't ever `return` from a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the scope of `this` within the functions will be the `window`. You need to cache the object reference in a variable and call that, like this:

```js
var Dog = function(name, type) {
    var _this = this;
    
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    
    this.normalObjFunc = function() {
        _this.name = "kl";
    }
    
    var retfunc = function() {
        return _this.name;
    }
    return retfunc;
}

var dogObj = new Dog("hj", "labrador");
console.log(dogObj());
```

Alternatively you can `prototype` the functions to keep the scope of `this`, however you would need to change your logic as it means that the return value of `Dog()` could not be the function.

```js
var Dog = function(name, type) {        
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

Dog.prototype.normalObjFunc = function() {
  this.name = "kl";
}
Dog.prototype.retfunc = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var dogObj = new Dog("hj", "labrador");
console.log(dogObj.retfunc());
```